# What is the meaning of Markup Language?

Tags: html

I want to know the meaning of Markup language. Because one of my teacher asked me what is meant by the word "Markup" in HTML(HyperText Markup Language)?

Comment: Did you try searching [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language)?

Comment: You ask bad questions. [Click here before you post your next one.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Comment: Yes, but i can't find a simple meaning

Answer (score 0):

The `Markup` in HyperText Markup Language tells that the 'language' is meant to describe markup like in a  document.

That the web would be a web of documents was the early thought for the web since the web was primarily used for research documents.